# Blender ImportError: cannot import name

Tags: python, python-2.7, blender

I am really almost giving up on trying to create an import-export module addon to Blender 2.68 and it seems that it is an insurmountable python problem (Blender uses python 3.3).
I see plenty of questions in stackoverflow on this topic but none of them answers my problem.
Part of my script:

```
if "bpy" in locals():
    import imp
    imp.reload(xplane_ui)
    print ("xplane_ui reloaded.")
    imp.reload(explane_import)
    print ("All modules reloaded.")

else:
    import bpy
    from io_explane import xplane_ui
    print ("xplane_ui imported.")
    from io_explane import explane_import #this is line 47
    print ("All modules imported")
```

I added extra print lines to see what is happening.
Here is the trace result:

```
Read new prefs: C:\Users\BT\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.68\config\userpref.blend
found bundled python: C:\blender-2.68a-windows32\2.68\python
xplane_ui imported
All modules imported
xplane_ui imported.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\blender-2.68a-windows32\2.68\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 294, in enable
    mod = __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\blender-2.68a-windows32\2.68\scripts\addons\io_explane\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from io_explane import explane_import
ImportError: cannot import name explane_import
```

This is so queer. I presume python progresses from top to bottom but how would it progress through
lines 46, 47 and 48 and then change decision on line 47 and announce it could not do it after having obviously done it?
Either python is a useless programmng language or blender is broken or both. Either way the error trapping routines are extremely unhelpful.

Comment: I should have mentioned I do not need the file xplane_ui. I deliberately added that file to test it and it appears that blender or python will import some files but not others. I have also checked the rejected file explane_import with Komodo Edit and there are no errors. The mystery gets bigger by the minute.

Comment: Tried inserting another know good file from another addon. It loaded OK.
Then tried renaming this file to explane_import and it still loaded OK.
This suggests that the real problem is that blender rather than python is rejecting my file due to something in the contents.

Comment: Conclusion is that the file I am attempting to import contains data that blender is rejection. This is not a python problem. The question could be deleted as it is probably no help to other users.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Blender, but could it be that you should import `xplane_import`?

Comment: Ah thanks. I missed that. It should read explane_import in every place in my question. I changed code and file name to xplane_import to se if I got a different result but same thing.